# Monitoring us president promises between times

Tags: united-states

Nominees for president elections make very promises. In action, after election, the  resolute on the some promises; but about some others...

Is there a media/NGO/... that Monitor us president promises time to time, e.g. every month/year?

Comment: I assume you're familiar with politifact.com? Not exactly what you want, but closest I could think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2017/politics/tracking-trumps-promises/), [Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/), and [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/politics/trump-promise-tracker/) are tracking Trumps promises.

[Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/obameter/) also tracked Obamas promises.

I am not aware of any trackers for other presidents. I'm also not sure how meaningful these really are (a president could have a lot of small, simple to fulfill promises, or may be unable to fulfill promises due to factors outside their control).

Comment: @user1 Keep in mind that all media outlets will always have some political leanings, so any judgement rendered on a promise should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I disagree. I believe that politifact, at least, tries to use factual data to render decisions. I do agree the commentary can get biased (and the puns are truly awful), but the ultimate lie/truth rating seems valid.